# Wix installer: How to set a default value to a combo box

Tags: wix

I am using a Combo Box in a dialog and when I open my setup, the combo box is empty with none of the values, only after I click on it, I can choose it's values. 
Is there a way to set a value BY DEFAULT
(I have tried Default="yes" and it did not help)

```
    <Control Id="DataBaseType" Type="ComboBox" Property="DATABASETYPE" Width="213" Height="16" X="100" Y="105" ComboList="yes" Sorted="no" Default="yes" >
      <ComboBox Property="DATABASETYPE" >
        <ListItem Text="MsSQL" Value="MsSQL" />
        <ListItem Text="MySQL" Value="MySQL" />
      </ComboBox>
    </Control>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set default value of property `DATABASETYPE` in your `Product.wxs`, for example `<Property Id="DATABASETYPE" Value="MySQL" />`